# why hibernate always inform me that it can not resolve the path file listed in cfg.xml?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, maven

I think i have put the correct files into the correct places.. can anyone help ?
i have one cfg.xml as following:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">123456</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>

    <mapping resource="com/sadproject/pojo/User.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/sadproject/pojo/Order.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/sadproject/pojo/Customer.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/sadproject/pojo/Manager.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/sadproject/pojo/Department.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/sadproject/pojo/Item.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/sadproject/pojo/Category.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
```

but i dont know why when i run the userTest: and the system informs me that :Unknown entity: com.sadproject.pojo.User.
while i actually put the correct file into the correct place
[enter image description here][1]

why the target folder can not resolve the files?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE9QX.png

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the files end up on the class path? With Maven, you normally have to put these files into `src/main/resources`. The Maven build usually ignores i.e. doesn't copy any files from `src/main/java` into the target.

Comment: yes i confirm. since i have posted this question after searching the related topic questions.

Comment: Usually IntelliJ has a good idea of the class path as it is during runtime, so there must be something wrong with your setup.

Comment: perhaps, thanks your Christian, i will try to reinstall IDEA again.